# Meteor is stuck on "Starting app on Android Device" after app is already installed

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, adb

When I run `meteor run adroid-device` it all works fine:

- Meteor builds successfully (It's an empty project so it should do that)
- Meteor starts everything
- Meteor build the APK
- The APK installation window pops up on my device
- I install the app and start it

But Meteor never realizes that. I think. It's stuck on `Starting app on Android Device`

I've tried running it with `--verbose` but when it comes to the critical point it just says:

```
(...)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.085 secs
Built the following apk(s): evice            |
    /path/to/meteor/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Using apk: /path/to/meteor/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Package name: com.idliu073otjcijgz5qn4
   Starting app on Android Device            /
```

[EDIT]

After testing on another phone it worked just fine. Maybe it's a problem with the Huawei phone? On the other phone I did't get a message asking for installation - it just installed the app and opened it.

Comment: please uninstall of previous app from your phone !!

Comment: @Aboopallikara I already tried this. It doesn't change it.